# Buffer Polygon on Point in Polygon Query

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.4

I would like to buffer the warning polygon by two miles can anyone help me with 
this so if ema personal are with in to miles of the warning the are listed, I've been trying to use ST Buffer (to expand the polygon coverage for the search) but cant seem to get it right? Is it in Meters (3218.69)? I'm using the latest opengeo suite.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ema.name) 
ST_X(ema.geom),ST_Y(ema.geom),ema."name", torpoly.expire
FROM ema INNER JOIN torpoly ON ST_Within(ema.geom, ST_BUFFER(torpoly.geom) 
ORDER BY ema."name"
```

Comment: EMA is point, torpoly is Polygon is the geom, EPSG:4326 I take it I'm using map units instead of meters from what I tried to figure out today.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are either:

1. Use an appropriate projected coordinate system for the region that uses linear units in metres or feet (UTM, State plane, etc.). All distance calculations on `geometry` types use a Cartesian coordinate system, which is quick and simple.
2. Use the `geography` type, which does distance calculations on objects with EPSG:4326 (lat/lon) with distance units in metres. If you don't want to change the data types, you can use a `geom::geography` cast, and maybe make an index on that cast.

And never do ST_Within(.., ST_Buffer()) for this type of analysis. It is slower and imperfect. Instead, use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), which finds all `geometry`/`geography` objects within a distance threshold of each other, which is just like a buffer. This function may use a spatial GiST index, if present.